# How to check username and password from a CSV. file

Tags: python, pandas, csv

This is a school project that I'm trying to do, we have to create a program that asks the user if they have already had an account or not. If not they would have to enter a username, the program will have to check whether the username is already used or not.

```
import csv

with open('accountdatabase.csv')as csvfile:
    datareader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in datareader:
        print("###################################")

accountq = input("Do You Have An Account? Y/N:  ")

create = "pending"
while create != "completed":
    if accountq == "N":
        print("Please Create An Account:")
        print("")
        username = input("Please Enter Your Username: ")
        password = input("Please Enter A Password: ")
        if row[0] == username:
            print("Sorry Username Is Already Taken")
        else:
            print("Username Accepted")
            create = "completed"
            break
```

However, when writing the code, I came an across a logic error where whenever I add a new username it only checks the last username on the row, meaning the previous one is not being checked, this leads to the user being able to create a new account with the same usernames.

**I still struggle calling in specific data from a specific Period and row no.**

This is how I structure my data in the .csv file:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YGqVH.png)

Comment: Opps forgot to name the image description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just keep a list of usernames when you parse the csv file:

```
import csv

usernames = []
with open('accountdatabase.csv')as csvfile:
    datareader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in datareader:
        usernames.append(row[0])

.....

if username in usernames:
    print("Sorry Username Is Already Taken")
```

This approach keeps the names in memory. This isn't exactly scalable, as it uses a ton of memory (`O(N)` space). You could also reread the csv and if you come across the username quit, but that would take `O(N)` time. Neither approach is really scalable. But either solution will work for this project. I'd recommend keeping them in memory since this is a small project, which is what the code above does.

Comment: Thank you, but I tried it and it still only check the last username on the list. For some reason, it doesn't check the whole list

Comment: How so? Where's your updated code? Print the `usernames` list you check because it should have every username in it. You're not still checking against `row[0]` are you?

Comment: Wait actually I'll take that back I just fixed it, thank you for your code it did work but I just didn't use it correctly in the first place.

Comment: No problem! Please accept the answer if you wouldn't mind :)

Answer (score 1):

Kindly rewrite the code :

-rest of the code-

for row in dataheader:
   if row[0] == username

-rest of the code-

**Hope It works**

Answer (score 1):

You can do this easily using `pandas` library. The solution will be fast and smaller.

Note: you may have to install `pandas` if don't already have it.

```
pip install -U pandas
```

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('accountdatabase.csv', sep=',')

# Your trial username
trial_username = 'bob12'

# The username column is called 'username' in the CSV file
if trial_username in df['username'].tolist():
    print('Username NOT available.')
else:
    print('Username available.')
```

## Let's try with some dummy data

We assume that once you read in the file using `pandas.read_csv` method, you have a dataframe `df` as follows.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'username': ['bob12', 'rickrock', 'jango.tango', 'captain.america'], 'password': None})
print(df)
```

**Output**:

```
          username password
0            bob12     None
1         rickrock     None
2      jango.tango     None
3  captain.america     None
```

Now you want to test if a certain **username** is **`already taken`** or **`available`**. Here is the code for that.

```py
trial_username = 'bob12'

if trial_username in df['username'].tolist():
    print('Username NOT available.')
else:
    print('Username available.')
```

Result:

```
Username NOT available.
```

## Design

#### Check objective: SignIn or SignUp

If **SignUp**:
1. Check username availability.
1. If username is available: let user provide a password. 
1. Save username and password to file.

If **SignIn**:
1. Check match for both username and password.
1. If match found: Credentials are VALID, else INVALID.

### Check for SignUp Credentials

Assume this is your data.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'username': ['bob12', 'rickrock', 'jango.tango', 'captain.america'], 'password': None})
df['password'] = ['passw0rd']*df.shape[0]
print(df)
```

Dummy Data:

```
          username  password
0            bob12  passw0rd
1         rickrock  passw0rd
2      jango.tango  passw0rd
3  captain.america  passw0rd
```

> **Check username and password validity for an existing user**:

```py
user_username = 'bob12'
user_password = 'passw0rd'
valid_user = df['password'].loc[df['username'] == user_username] == user_password
print(valid_user)
```

Comment: That actually would make my code much easier and shorter actually thank you, however I can see that you have the username and password combined at the string/ pandas. So I don't know how I will check if the password mache the username's specific password when it comes to log in.

Comment: @Coding_Tutorials2019 Please consider **`voting up`** and **`accepting`** the solution.

Comment: Wait actually the code would require me to pip install which school computer restricts such actions. I was devasted after they didn't allow me to have GUI for my programn

Comment: @Coding_Tutorials2019 I didn't understand your question about username and password match. In case you want to also check if the password provided by any user matches the password on the file (`csv`), I will add that in the solution. But, please understand that checking password and username match is a different problem than what you asked in the main question.

Comment: If you have trouble using setting this up in the school computer, have you considered using google colab environment? It is just like google docs, but for a Jupyter Notebook and is super easy to use. https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/welcome.ipynb#

Comment: I'm actually going to try that, it might actually work, fingers cross that school won't block the website

Comment: Okay. In that case you may not even need to install `pandas` as it is already available in Colab. Just in case you need to install any library using pip from Jupyter notebook environment inside colab, do this: `!pip install <library_name>`. For example, if you want to install `pandas`, this would be `!pip install -U -q pandas`. Adding the `-q` suppresses the installation log output. Good luck!